# How can I access the list of favorite contacts in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I access the list of favorite contacts in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, last time I checked at least :(

Comment: Is there any chance to get them from Address book?